# React.js: Get specific value as a string from state array (hooks)

Tags: reactjs

I want to get a specific value in my state array

The state array looks like this if I do console.log

```
profileModule  
(2) […]
​
0: Object { moduleId: "4E948025-1F1B-41E2-A18D-55AD8646810B", module: "Client Maintenance", description: "Client Enrollment", … }
​
1: Object { moduleId: "C77C1031-2714-483D-AE59-21C9CD5EBAEF", module: "Bank Maintenance", description: "Bank Enrollment", … }
​
length: 2
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

I want to get the moduleId and set it as String

I tried this, but it doesn't work. It says undefined.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const moduleId = profileModule.moduleId
    console.log("moduleId ", moduleId)
  }, [profileModule]);
```

Any help would do. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Profile Module is an array

You need to get the index of the profile module you would like to retrieve.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const moduleId = profileModule[0].moduleId // gets the 1st index
    console.log("moduleId ", moduleId)
  }, [profileModule]);
```

But I don't think you want this to be static. Do you know what index you want to retrieve?

## To Retrieve a list of IDs

You can use memo or callback on this code if you want to optimise.

```
const idsArray = profileModule 
  ? profileModule.map(({moduleId}) => moduleId);
  : [];
```

Comment: I would like to get all of the moduleId. e.g. "4E948025-1F1B-41E2-A18D-55AD8646810B","C77C1031-2714-483D-AE59-21C9CD5EBAEF"

Comment: Dont use useEffect. You can use useCallback to asign a value outside of the callback.

Comment: And after trying your code, it says profileModule[0].moduleId is undefined

Comment: Would this be correct, if I'm trying to get moduleId by row index? `const getModuleIds = useCallback((rowIndex) => {
    const moduleId = profileModule[rowIndex].moduleId 
    console.log("moduleId ", moduleId)
  })`